# How to Subscribe to a shared Service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, interceptor

I can't get my head around how to watch for new values in an observable of a service.
My final goal is to combine an interceptor, a service and a directive so display loading information to the user.
I've got an interceptor listening for http calls:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { LoadingService } from '../loading.service';
import { map, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class LoadingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private loadingSrv: LoadingService) {}

  public intercept(req, next): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.url === 'graphql') {
      console.log('first', req);
      this.loadingSrv.saveRequest(req);
    }
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      map(el => {
        if (req.url === 'graphql') {
        }
        return el;
      }),
      finalize(() => {
        console.log('final', req);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

if a request is found, he should trigger the loading service and fire a saving function.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadingService {
  public loadingQuerys: BehaviorSubject<[]> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  constructor() {}
  saveRequest(req) {
    this.loadingQuerys.next(req);
    // this.requests[req.body.operationName] = new BehaviorSubject({ isLoading: true });
  }
}
```

The loading service should emit the new req value to the behavior subject.
Now I want to subscribe to this BehaviorSubject from a directive.

```
import { Directive, Input, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingSpinnerComponent } from './loading-spinner.component';
import { LoadingService } from './loading.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[showLoadingSpinner]'
})
export class ShowLoadingSpinnerDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input('showLoadingSpinner') query: any;

  constructor(
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private loadingSpinner: LoadingSpinnerComponent,
    private factoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    public loadingSrv: LoadingService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const factory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(LoadingSpinnerComponent);
    console.log(this.query);
    this.loadingSrv.loadingQuerys.subscribe(console.log);
  }
}
```

My Problem is now, that he doesn't recognize in the subscriptions, that there's a new value.
Maybe because the service here is a new Instance?
How can I make the directive listening for any changes to detect if a query was fired and finished?

Comment: It looks like your directive should be able to access the service's observable.  Are you sure your `saveRequest()` method is getting fired?

Comment: Yeah. Console log is showing me

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pattern that might work for you. I can't tell what is going on precisely, but I would leave the `BehaviorSubject` private. It's also important to unsubscribe in your component.

In your loading service use:

```js
export interface LoadingState {
  req: any;
}

let _state: LoadingState = {
  req: null,
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoadingService {
  private store = new BehaviorSubject<LoadingState>(_state);
  private state$ = this.store.asObservable();

  req$ = this.state$.pipe(
    map((state) => {
      return state.req;
    }),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );

  constructor() {}
  saveRequest(req) {
    this.updateState({ ..._state, req });
  }

  private updateState(state: LoadingState) {
    this.store.next((_state = state));
  }
}
```

In your component

```js
  constructor(private loadingSrv: LoadingService) {}
  private onDestroy = new Subject<void>();
  req$: Observable<LoadingState> = this.loadingSrv.req$;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.req$.pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy)).subscribe((value) => {
      console.log(value);
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.onDestroy.next();
    this.onDestroy.complete();
  }
```

Comment: no, this is not working. 
I get the first new value in console at the end, but no new value after updateState was fired.

Comment: does taking out the `distinctUntilChanged()` help? I'd also put a console.log in the update state to make sure that is updating correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put the service into a not lazy loaded module.

Comment: It is not recommended to have any service "in" any module. Consider instead using `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})`